# Hangman Game in SWI Prolog (Enchance)

Tags: algorithm, prolog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hangman Game in SWI Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743564/hangman-game-in-swi-prolog)

I'm trying to enchance a simple hangman game in SWI Prolog with the following:

***1)*** By keeping up with the **WRONG** letters that have been guessed so far. If the user guesses a letter that has already been guessed wrong, the program should say 'You guessed that!' and just continue the game without increasing the counter.

***2)*** Lastly, add a counter that counts the number of incorrect guesses and quits the game when a certain number is reached. The program should tell the user that they lose, display what the phrase really was, and terminate. Duplicate guesses should not be counted as wrong.

How can i put these predicates together so that my progam runs for the above enchancements?
***1)***

```
alreadyGuessed(Guess, AnsCodes) :-
   memberchk(Guess, AnsCodes).
```

***2)***

```
processGuess(AnsList, BlankList, _, CountFailed) :-
  (   CountFailed == 5
  ->  format('Sorry, game over. You didn\'t guess (~s)~n', [AnsList])
  ;   write('Nope!'),
      CountFailed1 is CountFailed + 1,
      getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed1)
  ).
```

What i tried to do is:
Extend the predicate getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed)

***I provide you with the code and comments with the running version before my changes.***

**Edit:** Program now runs until you do 5 mistakes. Run it like `?- hangman(0).` 
Now i only need to NOT count the letters that have been used so far as wrong answers and display the appropriate message as listed above. Am i gonna do it by writting one more predicate `processGuess`?

```
% This top-level predicate runs the game.  It prints a 
% welcome message, picks a phrase, and calls getGuess.

% Ans = Answer
% AnsList = AnswerList

hangman(CountFailed):- 
    getPhrase(Ans), 
    !, 
    write('Welcome to hangman.'),
    nl,
    name(Ans,AnsList), 
    makeBlanks(AnsList, BlankList), 
    getGuess(AnsList,BlankList, CountFailed).

% Randomly returns a phrase from the list of possibilities.

getPhrase(Ans):-
    phrases(L), 
    length(L, X), 
    R is random(X), 
    N is R+1, 
    getNth(L, N, Ans).

% Possible phrases to guess.

phrases(['a_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words','one_for_the_money','dead_or_alive','computer_science']).

% Asks the user for a letter guess.  Starts by writing the 
% current "display phrase" with blanks, then asks for a guess and
% calls process on the guess.

getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed):- 
    name(BlankName, BlankList), 
    write(BlankName), 
    nl,  
    write('Enter your guess, followed by a period and return.'), 
    nl, 
    read(Guess),
    !, 
    name(Guess, [GuessName]), 
    processGuess(AnsList,BlankList,GuessName, CountFailed).

% Process guess takes a list of codes representing the answer, a list of codes representing the current
% "display phrase" with blanks in it, and the code of the letter that was just guessed.  If the guess
% was right, call substitute to put the letter in the display phrase and check for a win.  Otherwise, just
% get another guess from the user.

processGuess(AnsList,BlankList,GuessName, CountFailed):- 
    member(GuessName,AnsList), 
    !,
    write('Correct!'),
    nl, 
    substitute(AnsList, BlankList, GuessName, NewBlanks), 
    checkWin(AnsList,NewBlanks, CountFailed).

processGuess(AnsList, BlankList, _, CountFailed) :-
  (   CountFailed == 5
  ->  format('Sorry, game over. You didn\'t guess (~s)~n', [AnsList])
  ;   write('Nope!'),
      nl,
      CountFailed1 is CountFailed + 1,
      getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed1)
  ).

% Check to see if the phrase is guessed.  If so, write 'You win' and if not, go back and get another guess.

checkWin(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed):- 
    name(Ans, AnsList), 
    name(BlankName, BlankList), 
    BlankName = Ans, 
    !, 
    write('You win!').

checkWin(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed):- 
    getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed).


% getNth(L,N,E) should be true when E is the Nth element of the list L. N will always
% be at least 1.

getNth([H|T],1,H).

getNth([H|T],N,E):-
    N1 is N-1,
    getNth(T,N1,E1),
    E=E1.

% makeBlanks(AnsList, BlankList) should take an answer phrase, which is a list
% of character codes that represent the answer phrase, and return a list
% where all codes but the '_' turn into the code for '*'.  The underscores
% need to remain to show where the words start and end.  Please note that 
% both input and output lists for this predicate are lists of character codes.
% You can test your code with a query like this:
% testMakeBlanks:- name('csc_is_awesome', List), makeBlanks(List, BlankList), name(Towrite, BlankList), write(Towrite). 

makeBlanks(AnsCodes, BlankCodes) :-
  maplist(answer_blank, AnsCodes, BlankCodes).

answer_blank(Ans, Blank) :-
  Ans == 0'_ -> Blank = Ans ; Blank = 0'* .

% substitute(AnsList, BlankList, GuessName, NewBlanks) Takes character code lists AnsList and BlankList, 
% and GuessName, which is the character code for the guessed letter.  The NewBlanks should again be a 
% character code list, which puts all the guesses into the display word and keeps the *'s and _'s otherwise.
% For example, if the answer is 'csc_is_awesome' and the display is 'c*c_**_*******' and the guess is 's', the 
% new display should be 'csc_*s_***s***'.
% You can test your predicate with a query like this:
% testSubstitute:- name('csc_is_awesome', AnsList), name('c*c_**_*******', BlankList), name('s',[GuessName]), substitute(AnsList, BlankList, GuessName, NewBlanks),
%    name(Towrite, NewBlanks), write(Towrite). 

% Also, since the predicate doesn't deal directly with character codes, this should also work:
% substitute(['c','s','c'],['c','*','c'],'s',L).  L should be ['c','s','c'].

substitute(AnsCodes, BlankCodes, GuessName, NewBlanks) :-
     maplist(place_guess(GuessName), AnsCodes, BlankCodes, NewBlanks).

place_guess(Guess, Ans, Blank, Display) :-
    Guess == Ans -> Display = Ans ; Display = Blank.
```

Comment: Anyone who can help me out with question 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert this rule before `processGuess(AnsList, BlankList, _, CountFailed) :-`

```
processGuess(AnsList, BlankList, Guess, CountFailed):-
    memberchk(Guess, BlankList),
    write('You guessed that!'), nl,
    !, getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, CountFailed).
```

I placed inline the only call from `alreadyGuessed`

**edit** to change CountFailed to a FailedList:

```
processGuess(AnsList, BlankList, Guess, FailedList):-
    (  length(FailedList, 5)
    ->  ... signal game failure and stop ...
    ;   getGuess(AnsList, BlankList, [Guess|FailedList])
    )
```

Comment: Still `memberchk` isn't working. The program just bypasses the predicate where `memberchk` is listed.
What i actually want to do is that if for example there is no letter "n" in the word and the user had already pressed that letter "n" previously i want to print him that message and not increase the counter. What i tried to do:
    
    :-dynamic(store/1)
    store([]).
     
    alreadyGuessed(Guess):-
      retract(store(L)),
      member(Guess,L),
      assert(store(L)).

    alreadyGuessed(Guess):-
       retract(store(L)),
       not(member(Guess,L)),
       assert(store([Guess|L]).

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know why it isn't formatted the above comment.

Comment: The main idea is to make a list where i will put all the wrong letters the user gave and then everytime he gives a wrong letter i will first check the above list with the wrong letters and then all other checks. Sorry for all these questions, but this troubles me quite some time now.

Comment: I think that you should change `CountFailed` to a list: then instead of adding, `cons` the failed `GuessName` and check using length/2 for game failure. Try these to code on these hints. Place your actual code editing question if you still need help, I'll try to give advice...